# How to match first groups occurrence with regex?

Tags: java, regex

Example: https://regex101.com/r/n4x91E/1

**INPUT STRING :**

"I think we have to point certain things out to this man, and after that point some other things out to him as well"

**MY REGULAR EXPRESSION :**

```
(point).*(out)
```

**RETURNING WRONG RESULT :**

"I think we have to `point certain things out to this man, and after that point some other things out` to him as well"

**EXPECTING RESULT :**

"I think we have to `point certain things out` to this man, and after that point some other things out to him as well"

How to change my regular expression to get the first groups occurrence ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use a lazy quantifier for your regular expression like in this version:

https://regex101.com/r/n4x91E/2

```
(point).*?(out)
```

In the [Java documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/quant.html) this quantifier is called reluctant, but I think lazy is more commonly used...

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
(point).*?(out)
```

If you only want the first occurrence then don't use global flag... it only match the first occurrence . see the following link . Otherwise you can put the global flag 'g'

[Explanation](https://regex101.com/r/n4x91E/4)

Answer (score 1):

Make the regex non greedy:

```
(point.*?out)
```

**Sample code:**

```
String line = "I think we have to point certain things out to this man, and after that point some other things out to him as well";
String pattern = ".*(point.*?out).*";
Pattern r = Pattern.compile(pattern);
Matcher m = r.matcher(line);
if (m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group(1));
    System.out.println(m.group(2));
}
```

**Output:**

```
point certain things out
point some other things out
```